# Gradle Build Takes Error But Application Runs Properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, microservices

In my project, i use basically microservice architecture, spring boot, spring cloud and gradle etc.

When i tried to Gradle build, it takes error but when i tried to running to the my application, it runs properly.

I searched too many resource but i didn't find any solution. No solution suggestions worked for me and error explanation is not specific which it is too general

[Shared Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBJ72.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found to error's resource and error's solution. Error's resource some class contains @Autowired annotation in test package so for  this situation, I must use SpringBootTest and RunWith(SpringRunner.class). If I dont use, I take error. For me I used these annotations but SpringBootTest I use wrong location @SpringBootTest(classes = {ABC.class}) I changed to correct location and it works :).

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error complaining that what ever you marked with @Autowire, cannot point to an implementation. So mainly could be for 2 reasons.

1. You have an interface, but you have not implement it via a class
2. You have implemented one with a class but it's not in the spring dependency injectable context, in this case mark it as @Component with the relevant interface implementation.

Comment: i checked every class but i think everything is done for main package. But when i run test package, mostly they take fails. I think this errors source is SpringBootTest annotation or ActiveProfiles annotation

Comment: By the way some files contains autowired annotation in the test package and these files inherited from one class and inherited  class marks runwith(springrunner.class), springboottest, ignore, enablescheduling, transactional and activeprofiles. I think error source is one of this annotations